# Scrollbar - tkinter GUI - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I've been trying to create a scrollbar on a frame by trying to combine two codes written by Bryan Oakley. ( The code is not mine).

The first one is code the creates multiple frame using classes and the other one uses canvas to create a scrollable frame.

```
import tkinter as tk


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}
    for F in (StartPage, Example):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[page_name] = frame

        # put all of the pages in the same location;
        # the one on the top of the stacking order
        # will be the one that is visible.
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame("StartPage")

def show_frame(self, page_name):
    '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()
```

The original code for does not use parent nor controller as parameters but uses roots instead. By switching to parent and controller the labels created in the function "inmatning" are moved all the way to the write and the scrollbar doesn't show.

```
class Example(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
    self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

    self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                              tags="self.frame")

    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
    self.inmatning()

def inmatning(self):

    allbio = läs_fil()
    x = 0
    while x < len(allbio):

        label = tk.Label(self, text="\n"+allbio[x].namn)
        label.pack()
        lista =["Barn", "Vuxna", "Penionärer"]
        l = 0
        while l < len(lista):
            label1= tk.Label(self, text="Antal " + lista[l])
            label1.pack()
            enter1 = tk.Entry(self)
            enter1.pack()

            l=l+1

        x=x+1


def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
```

This here is normal frame that works without any problem ( not using canvas of course ) 
    class Menu(tk.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Här kan du väljer mellan de följande 6 alternativen")
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Example",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Example"))
    button1.pack()

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Beläggning",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Beläggning"))

    button2.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
def inmatning(self):
    ...
    while x < len(allbio):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="\n"+allbio[x].namn)
```

What is it doing? It is creating some labels, each with a parent of `self`. What is `self`? It's a frame that has an canvas, and inside that canvas is a frame. Widgets that are inside that inner frame will be scrolled when the canvas is scrolled.

The whole point of the scrollable frame is that put put widgets *in the inner frame*, not in the outer frame. It's the inner frame (the one inside the canvas) that should contain all of the widgets.

Try changing your label creation to this:

```
    label = tk.Label(self.frame, text="\n"+allbio[x].namn)
```

I don't know if that's the only problem, but it's certainly part of the problem. I can't simply cut and paste your code to test it out since you have code spread among several blocks, and didn't include all of your code.

Comment: Omg that fixed everything! thank you so much! I really appreciate that ! I wish I could vote you up, but my reputation is to low...

Comment: Just one more question , If you don't mind! the labels are appearing at the left side of the window, how to I center the labels to the middle of the frame?